# How to count anagrams in a string?

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to solve this question:

> Have the function `CountingAnagrams` take the `str` parameter and determine how many anagrams exist in the string.

Examples:

Input: `"aa aa odg dog gdo"` — Output: `2`

Input: `"a c b c run urn urn"` — Output: `1`

I tried this solution but it does not display the correct answer. What am I doing wrong?

```js
const CountingAnagrams = (str) => {
  let l = str.length,
    c = 0,
    c1,
    c2;

  if (l % 2 == 0) {
    c1 = str.slice(0, l / 2).split("");
    c2 = str.slice(l / 2).split("");
    
    let l2 = c1.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < l2; i++) {
      let id = c2.indexOf(c1[i]);
      
      if (id !== -1) {
        c2[id] = " ";
      }
      else {
        c += 1;
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    return "-1";
  }
  
  return c;
};

console.log("cars are very cool so are arcs and my os", CountingAnagrams("cars are very cool so are arcs and my os"));
console.log("aa aa odg dog gdo", CountingAnagrams("aa aa odg dog gdo"));
console.log("a c b c run urn urn", CountingAnagrams("a c b c run urn urn"));
```

Comment: @user4642212 Thats how it is in the question. Because of RUN and URN. I posted the entire question now.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to provide code that can be run here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What kind of “solution” is that? Right from the get-go: if the string length is odd, it returns `"-1"`; this seems completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: 1. split into words.  2. create object to hold sorted words as keys and array of words as value.  3. for each word, sort it to be a key in object.  4. if key doesn't exist, create key with value empty array (`[]`).  5. if word doesn't exist in value, `push` it.  6. repeat 3 until all words processed.  7. Iterate over object and count how many keys have value of length > 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
const CountingAnagrams = (str) => {
  // Set() helps to remove all the duplicates
  const wordUnique = new Set(str.split(/\s+/)),
    wordArray = [
      ...wordUnique
    ],
    hash = {};
  let count = 0;
  
  
  wordArray.forEach((word) => {
    // Key will be the sorted word e.g. cba will become abc
    let key = word.split('').sort().join('');
    
    // If there is an anagram they will have the same key so whenever the key is avaialable in the hash count will be updated
    if (key in hash) {
      count += 1;
    }
    else {
      // true is assigned just for making the key available in the hash
      hash[key] = true;
    }
  });
  
  return count;
};

console.log("cars are very cool so are arcs and my os", CountingAnagrams("cars are very cool so are arcs and my os"));
console.log("aa aa odg dog gdo", CountingAnagrams("aa aa odg dog gdo"));
console.log("a c b c run urn urn", CountingAnagrams("a c b c run urn urn"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Sliding Window Solution C++ //(count is stored in ans and anagram positions is in vector v

```
  vector<int> findAnagrams(string s, string ana) {
 unordered_map<char, int> m;
for(auto it : ana) m[it]++;

int k=ana.length();
int count=m.size();

int i=0, j=0;
int ans=0;
vector<int>v;
while(j<s.length()){

    if(m.find(s[j])!=m.end()){
        m[s[j]]--;
        if(m[s[j]]==0) count--;
    }
    
    if((j-i+1)<k) j++;
    
    else if((j-i+1)==k){

        if(count==0){
            ans++;
            v.push_back(i);
        } 

        if(m.find(s[i])!=m.end()){
            m[s[i]]++;
            if(m[s[i]]==1) count++;
        }

        i++;
        j++;
    }
}
    cout<<ans;
      return v;}
```